# Gitlab-ci fails at copying files

Tags: reactjs, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using gitlab-ci and gitlab runner to deploy my React app to my server.
Here is my code:

```
image: node:alpine

variables: 
  PUBLIC_URL: https://example.com

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - some-tag
    - another-tag
  script:
    - echo "Building deploy package"
    - pwd
    - npm install
    - mv .env.example .env
    - echo ".env file changed!"
    - CI='' npm run build
    - echo "Build successful"
    - ls
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
      - build
  only:
    - master

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - some-tag
    - another-tag
  script:
    - echo "Current Directory:"
    - pwd
    - ls
    - echo "Deploying to server"
    - cp -rv ./build/* /dir/path-in-my-server/
    - echo "Deployed"
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
      - build
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://example.com
  only:
    - master
```

Every steps works well, but `cp -rv ./build/* /dir/path-in-my-server/` is not working. It giving this error:

```
cp: can't create '/dir/path-in-my-server/asset-manifest.json': No such file or directory
cp: can't create '/dir/path-in-my-server/favicon.ico': No such file or directory
cp: can't create '/dir/path-in-my-server/index.html': No such file or directory
cp: can't create '/dir/path-in-my-server/manifest.json': No such file or directory
cp: can't create directory '/dir/path-in-my-server/static': No such file or directory
Cleaning up file based variables
00:03
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I have observe few times that gitlab-ci has sometimes trouble with path starting with './', would you try "cp -rv build/* /..." ?

Comment: I've tried otherwise, but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by using `$PWD` env variable instead of relative paths like `./`. GitLab seems to have a problem with relative paths in `cp` and `mv` commands.

```yaml
script:
    - cp -rv ${PWD}/some-directory/* /your-dest-dir/
```